# Consideration for a little bit heavy database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

#### Environment information

- **OS** : Windows Server 2012 R2 ( 64bit )
- **RAM** : 16.00GB
- **CPU** : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 @ 2.40GHz
- **SQL** : Windows SQL Server 2012 Standard

#### Brief Database Data Information

- Among more than 10 tables, one of them has *varbinary(max)* type column
- The table has more than 1m records and each column has thumbnail data that takes up about 20k

#### Brief Table Spec

- **Table name** : RegisteredThumbnail
- **Column name** : UserId, ThumbData, Created, Updated
- **Column type** : int, varbinarymax, datetime, datetime
- **Used space info** : row : 1,034,300 | reserved : 34,092,160 KB | data : 34,054,872 KB | index_size : 31040 KB | unused : 6248 KB

#### Query

```
SELECT * FROM RegisteredThumbnail WHERE UserId = 512315
```

This query takes about 6:45 minutes to fetch the expected row.

To overcome this, is indexing the only option for me?

Changing the way image data is stored by replacing the binary data to image url as a string data will help a lot?

Since this is a currently operating system, changing the column is not a good idea though.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

No indexes have been configured yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This table should have a clustered index on `UserId`. If there is no more than one thumbnail per user, then the clustered index can be the primary key.

Since you say you have a currently-running system on SQLServer 2012 standard edition, online index builds are not possible. You could wait for a low-activity period to create the index, or create a new table, migrate the data into it, then switch to using the new table.

The table should ideally look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RegisteredThumbnail
(
    UserId       INT            NOT NULL,
    ThumbData    VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Created      DATETIME2(7)   NOT NULL,
    Updated      DATETIME2(7)   NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_RegisteredThumbnail PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserId ASC)
)
```

Since you cannot recreate the table, this is the index you need to create:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_RegisteredThumbnail_UserId
ON RegisteredThumbnail(UserID ASC)
```

As you're on 2012 Standard, this will be an "offline" operation - it'll block activity on this table while the index is being built. Given it's only a million rows, it should not take too long to build, however it does have to scan the table in order to do it, so you'll be limited by how fast it can read that data.

Answer (score 2):

- The server has too little memory. 16GB is the amount of memory found in a high end tablet. That said, this may be secondary because *varbinary* aside, the database is quite small. But even that is overloading the server memory. This is quite important because of...
- For most database use, disk speed is paramount, CPU does not matter (because memory as cache and disk speed for when the cache is overflowing are what matters and the CPU is not really taxed). Database servers often have very carefully planned disk layouts - or low performance. We do not necessarily talk about "a few disks". My low end database server here has 48GB memory and uses a total of 10 SSD and 2 HDD for data and log files - because I need the I/O.
- Indexes are the only way. They are *the* database way to not have to run through the whole table (a.k.a. Table Scan). You should have standard indexes (clustered primary key, all foreign keys) and others considered necessary after analysis of the queries.